# Java 7 to be run in 32 bit on mac

Tags: java, desktop-application, java-7

I am building a desktop Java application. It uses a third party framework for some low level work (it is in C and I have used JNA).

On my Windows Machine, when I do `Native.loadLibrary("EDSDK.dll", EdSdkLibrary.class, options);` it works perfectly well. On Mac when I try to do `Native.loadLibrary("EDSDK.framework", EdSdkLibrary.class, options);` it threw  `UnsatisfiedLinkError` saying: `mach-o, but wrong architecture`

My java 7 version is 64 bit and the framework is 32 bit based. On a different mac containing Java6, when I ran Java in 32 bit mode, the application works well.
This confirms the exception thrown was because of 32 bit incompatibility and I need to use 32 bit only(which is obvious).

This is the irritating part- In Java 7, `-d32` option doesn't work and Oracle no longer gives Java 7 in 32 bit. How do I run my Java 7 in 32 bit so that I can use the third party framework? Open JDK? Or use Java 6 and use it in 32 bit mode. But Oracle no longer provides Java 6 for Mac.

Any other alternative??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the [Apple Java 6 JDK](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572), which does include a 32 bit JVM.  But I doubt there will be much in the way of future security updates for Java 6, so you would be better off getting hold of a 64 bit version of the native framework and using that with Oracle Java 7.